# Passing MVC data to Knockout viewmodel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I have a pretty simple object coming back from my MVC controller

```
public class Company 
{
   public int CompanyID { get; set; } 
   public string CompanyName { get; set; } 
}
```

These are bound to a `<select>` element on the page that is bound by Knockout like so

#### HTML

```
<select data-bind="options: companies, optionsText: 'CompanyName', value: selectedCompany, optionsCaption: 'Select a company'" class="form-control" ></select>
```

#### Viewmodel

```
self.companies = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CompaniesAvailable)));
```

This binding works perfectly on the Create page, but on the Edit page, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make my `<select>` have the selected value from the `Company` object being passed to the page from my MVC viewmodel.

I'm trying to do my POST for editing a record without using AJAX if it's possible.

So I have this

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    TimeEntryViewModel vm = new TimeEntryViewModel();
    TimeEntry selected = new TimeEntry();
    selected = entry.GetEntryById(id);

    vm.EntryToAdd = selected;
    vm.EmployeeSelected = userDetails.GetUser(selected.UserId);

    vm.CompaniesAvailable = vm.EmployeeSelected.Companies;
    vm.SelectedCompany = vm.EmployeeSelected.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CompanyID == selected.CompanyId);

    return View(vm);
}
```

I'm not sure what the next step is to make it so that either the `CompanyID` or the `CompanyName` on the class is selected in the dropdown and populated in my Knockout VM

Here is some of the relevant code of the KO Viewmodel

#### Knockout Viewmodel

```
var viewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.userId = ko.observable(@Model.EntryToAdd.UserId);
    self.companies = ko.observableArray(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.CompaniesAvailable)));
    self.selectedCompany = ko.observable();
    self.companyId = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.selectedCompany()) {
            return self.selectedCompany().CompanyID;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }, this);
 }
```

The `self.companyId` computed function is databinding to a hidden field on the MVC form so it's picked up by the controller

```
@Html.Hidden("CompanyId", "", new { data_bind = "value: companyId()" })
```

Passing data directly from the MVC model to the Knockout VM seems a little hacky in my opinion, so if there is a better approach for this, I would appreciate the extra effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set the `optionsValue` to 'CompanyID' of your `data-bind`, and change the `selectedCompany` observable to `selectedCompanyID` and set it accordingly. By doing that you will be comparing two numbers instead of two *different* javascript objects.

Update the binding to:

```
<select data-bind="value: selectedCompanyID, options: companies, optionsValue: 'CompanyID', optionsText: 'CompanyName', optionsCaption: 'Select a company'" class="form-control" ></select>
```

Drop the `companyID` property and replace `selectedCompany` with `selectedCompanyID` of the JS view model:

```
var viewModel = function () {
    // ... snipped ...
    self.selectedCompanyID = ko.observable(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.SelectedCompanyID)));
}
```

Replace `SelectedCompany` with `SelectedCompanyID` of the CS view model:

```
vm.SelectedCompanyID = selected.CompanyId;
```

Comment: Could you whip up a quick code sample from what I've provided? Not sure I follow

Comment: Let me know if you follow the code I've added, or no.

Comment: That worked! Thanks! I've never understood the difference between value and optionsValue.. I was toying around with these before I posted the question and didn't really get it.